# The "Where is this used?" feature, does it actually work, well at least for list buttons?

Tags: apex, javascript

I'm going through the JS buttons to convert to lightning. The list buttons... when going through them it doesn't say they're on a page layout when you click on "where is this used"...at least for 90% of these buttons. So part of me is thinking this works part of the time.

To be honest I'm new at the company, so i don't know which ones are actually used. Can anyone confirm that this feature actually works.

Answer (score 0):

I can't confirm or deny whether this feature works (though we too had our suspicions).

However, when we did this sort of exercise we simply tried to delete the target metadata items (apex classes, buttons, components etc.). If they are used somewhere the deletion is prevented and links are presented to the usages.

Of course, if they are unused they just disappear. But we view that as positive - we immediately get rid of unused cruft.